# Rstudio knit pdf in Rstudio loadNamespace(name): there is no package called 'rmarkdown'

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I just updated to Rstudio Version 0.98.1074. When I try to use compile notebook with a script or Knit pdf with an .rmd I get

> Error in loadNamespace error: there is no package called 'rmarkdown'

yet I can type `rmarkdown::render("filename.rmd")` and it will render the document.  I removed `rmarkdown` and re-installed with `RStudio` and it did not help.  I've updated all my packages and I'm using R3.1.1.

This is a minor inconvenience since I have a workaround but thought I'd post in case there is a solution that I can't find.

Comment: Interesting. I cannot reproduce it. What does `find.package('rmarkdown')` say?

Comment: I noticed that it worked fine in a different directory with the same script and .rmd files worked fine with knit button in other directories.  I narrowed it down to the .rdata file in the directory with the script.  Even though I was using a different workspace somehow having that .Rdata file in the directory messed things up. Once I deleted that .Rdata from the directory then all was well. I can send the files if you want to try and reproduce.

Comment: ps. to answer your question  > find.package('rmarkdown')
[1] "C:/Users/JLaake/Desktop/RHome/RLibrariesx86-32/rmarkdown"

Comment: I contacted Yihui offlist. We concluded that it was a "dirty" .Rdata file. Part of my confusion was not realizing that Rstudio switches to the directory containing the script and loading that .Rdata when it compiles or renders the document. So changing the current working directory at the console did nothing. The script had to be moved to a different directory. Yihui suggested the following:  I turned
off both options "Restore from .RData" and "Save R workspace to
.RData" from Tools => Global Options in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I received almost the exact same error when trying to use Rmarkdown on Windows, within Cygwin:

```
loadNamespace(name): there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
```

Everything worked fine within Rstudio, but didn't work when I tried to auto-knit some `.Rmd` files within Cygwin.

My library path in Rstudio:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Gravitas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"
```

My library path as reported in Cygwin, when running `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\R.exe`:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"
```

The problem:

- When Rstudio is run in non-Administrator mode, it cannot write anything into `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library` as this directory is write-protected.
- Thus, Rstudio writes new packages into the user profile directory, which is freely writable.
- However, Cygwin was not aware of the user's profile directory, so it could not find all of the newly installed packages.

The solution was to set this environment variable within Cygwin:

```
export R_LIB=C:/Users/Gravitas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3
```

Now, the path reported Cygwin is:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Gravitas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"
```

And now, I can call bash scripts within Cygwin to auto-knit `.Rmd files`.