# Rmarkdown does not find library path

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown

Using macOS 10.12, I am trying to knit an Rmd file from the terminal.  I have just installed R from homebrew, but when I try the following:

```
$ Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd')"
```

An error appears:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I am assuming, base on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470909/rstudio-knit-pdf-in-rstudio-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rma), that one would need to export the library.

So I tried in R Studio:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"
```

and then in the terminal:

```
$ export R_LIB= usr/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library
```

but this throws an error:

```
-bash: export: `usr/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library': not a valid identifier
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here would be much appreciated!

Comment: missing the leading slash in your export.

Comment: `/usr/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library` doesn't throws the same error

Comment: which doesn't match the returned value from `.libPaths()`

Comment: `$ export R_LIB=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library` runs but again, the same error is thrown.  Any ideas? Rmarkdown is in the library

Comment: The same error? If you have the correct path, you won't receive the "not a valid identifier" message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have spaces around the `=` sign when assigning in bash. This is the cause of the "not a valid identifier" error.

```
export R_LIB=usr/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library
```

This will solve your Bash problem, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in R. I find it exceeding unlikely that you have a `usr/Library` directory. You can set [an environment variable](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) called `R_LIBS_USER` that tells R where to look for user-specific libraries, as well as `R_LIBS`:

> The library search path is initialized at startup from the environment variable `R_LIBS` (which should be a colon-separated list of directories at which R library trees are rooted) followed by those in environment variable `R_LIBS_USER`. Only directories which exist at the time will be included.
>
> By default `R_LIBS` is unset, and `R_LIBS_USER` is set to directory ‘`R/R.version$platform-library/x.y`’ of the home directory (or ‘`Library/R/x.y/library`’ for CRAN macOS builds), for R *x*.*y*.*z*.

I suspect you may be looking for:

```
export R_LIBS=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library
```

Or, if it's user specific:

```
export R_LIBS=$HOME/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library
```